# CicleCI trouble with buldah build

Tags: dockerfile, circleci, buildah

There was a problem with the image build in CircleCI, I don't understand why it doesn't work with the ruby ​​image

Here proplem -

```
 buildah bud -f ./Dockerfile -t hiq-intelligence-api:83948762
STEP 1/10: FROM ruby:3.2.1
? Please select an image: 
  2K▸ registry.fedoraproject.org/ruby:3.2.1
    registry.access.redhat.com/ruby:3.2.1
    docker.io/library/ruby:3.2.1
    quay.io/ruby:3.2.1

  ERRO[0600] signal: hangup                               
ERRO[0600] (Unable to determine exit status)            

Too long with no output (exceeded 10m0s): context deadline exceeded
```

Why do they ask to choose an image? if i do buildah bud ?

although I tried with centos7 - everything is ok